# How to connect to a Mosquitto broker on a Raspberry Pi through web sockets?

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I am trying to connect to a Raspberry Pi that has the Mosquitto broker installed. The client on the RPi is connected using:

```
client.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883, 60)
```

I tried to connect to it on my MQTT JavaScript client using the following specifications but I failed:

```
client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("10.101.125.190", 1883,"myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));
```

I also tried changing the port to `8080` from the JavaScript side but I still failed. If I change the port to `8080` on the RPi then it won't even connect.

This is the error that I am getting at the moment:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://10.101.125.190:1883/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

So, what do I need to change to fix this error? The RPi and my JS client are both in the same local network.

**Edit**: 
I forgot to mention that I have already tried this with `test.mosquitto.org - 8080` and it worked, but as soon as I change the address then I start getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

MQTT over websockets does not share the same port as native MQTT.

You will need to add a new listener to your mosquitto config.

You will need to add something like the following to the end of your /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf (or in a seperate file in /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.d)

```
listener 1884
protocol websockets
```

Then need to update your JavaScript to connect to port 1884 not 1883

You will also need to be using a version of mosquitto newer than than 1.4.x iirc the default version that is packaged for raspbian is too old. Follow the instructions [here](http://mosquitto.org/2013/01/mosquitto-debian-repository/) to get a newer version.

Comment: How about my client on the RPi, does it have be connected using the port 1884?

Comment: They will still need to use 1883 as they are talking native MQTT

Comment: I was flawlessly able to follow all the steps, but apparently I am still getting a slightly different error which is `WebSocket connection to 'ws://10.101.125.190:1884/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I got this at the end of of the output of `apt-get update` which says `N: Ignoring file 'mosquitto-wheezy.list.l' in directory 'etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename exention`. Could this have any relationship with the error? Do I need to reboot the RPi maybe?

Comment: Looks like you downloaded the `mosquitto-wheezy.list` file twice (hence one having the `.1` added to the end. you only need one copy of this file

Comment: So apparently I had the right version from before. The difference now is `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` instead of `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Comment: Apparently, there's no problem except that now I have to run mosquitto using the command `mosquitto` through terminal to make it work. I didn't have to do this before (run mosquitto individually), and it is a little inconvenient, but it is working. However, it doesn't show that there's any socket listening to port 1884 when I run mosquitto, how can I change that?

Comment: mosquitto needs to be told where it's config file is. Look at the man page

Comment: I reread the page twice now and I am not sure if I got you. How do I let mosquitto know where its config file is? I didn't change its directory. I'd really appreciate if you could guide me and help me through this.

Comment: After exploring a bit, I put and individual file in the `conf.d` directory to include `listener 1884, protocol webscokets`. However, that still didn't help!